# SQLAlchemy How to use JSON columns with indexes interchangeably between SQLite and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on defining a schema with sqlalchemy that works with multiple engine backends, notably sqlite and postgresql.

I'm having an issue because I have a JSON column with an index on it. This seems to work on sqlite, but with postgresql it complains that the index type can't be a btree. I've seen docs that highlight a JSONB type that is specific to the postgres dialect, but the issue is that my schema is declarative: I don't know if I'm going to connect to an SQLite or a PostgreSQL database.

As an example, here is a toy declarative schema:

```py
    # from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy import inspect
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column, Index
    from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, JSON
    from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

    CustomBase = declarative_base()

    class User(CustomBase):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, doc='unique internal id')
        name = Column(JSON)
        loose_identifer = Column(JSON, index=True, unique=False)
        # loose_identifer = Column(JSONB, index=True, unique=False)

    uri = 'sqlite:///test_sqlite_v7.sqlite'
    # uri = 'postgresql+psycopg2://admin:admin@localhost:5432/test_postgresql_v4.postgres'

    engine = create_engine(uri)
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()

    if 'postgresql' in uri:
        if not database_exists(uri):
            create_database(uri)

    inspector = inspect(engine)
    table_names = inspector.get_table_names()
    if len(table_names) == 0:
        CustomBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

    user_infos = [
        {'name': 'user1', 'loose_identifer': "AA" },
        {'name': 'user2', 'loose_identifer': "33" },
        {'name': 'user3', 'loose_identifer': 33 },
        {'name': 'user4', 'loose_identifer': 33 },
        {'name': 'user5', 'loose_identifer': "AA" },
        {'name': 'user6', 'loose_identifer': None},
        {'name': 'user7', 'loose_identifer': [1, 'weird']},
    ]
    for row in user_infos:
        user = User(**row)
        session.add(user)

    session.commit()

    import pandas as pd
    import json
    table_df = pd.read_sql_table('users', con=engine)
    table_df['loose_identifer'] = table_df['loose_identifer'].apply(repr)
    print(table_df)

    query = session.query(User.name, User.loose_identifer).filter(User.loose_identifer == json.dumps(33))
    results = list(query.all())
    print(f'results={results}')

    query = session.query(User.name, User.loose_identifer).filter(User.loose_identifer == json.dumps('33'))
    results = list(query.all())
    print(f'results={results}')
```

The `User` table has a `loose_identifer` column that I want to be allowed to be a fairly arbitrary JSON type, and I want to add an index on it. The main reason that I have it like this is because I have to support these "loose" identifiers that could be integers or strings.

Using a `Column(JSON, index=True, unique=False)` seems to work just fine when I use sqlite, but when I switch it to target a postgresql engine I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) data type json has no default operator class for access method "btree"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.

[SQL: CREATE INDEX ix_users_loose_identifer ON users (loose_identifer)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

I've tried adding the index explicitly by adding this class attribute:

```
    __table_args__ =  (
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885846/how-to-create-jsonb-index-using-gin-on-sqlalchemy
        Index(
            "ix_users_loose_identifer", loose_identifer,
            postgresql_using="gin",
        ),
    )
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. It's possible I'm doing something wrong in that declaration.

If I change `JSON` to `JSONB` in the above schema, it does work, but `JSONB` isn't compatible with sqlite, so my question is: how to I declare my schema with json columns that will be indexed using syntax that is compatible between sqlite and postgresql backends?

Comment: I have posted a closely related question in the SQLAlchemy Discussion board: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9530

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem. Here is a more succinct demonstration of the issue:

```py
from sqlalchemy import JSON, Column, Integer, Unicode, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = "nodes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    key = Column(Unicode(1023), index=True, nullable=False)
    ancestors = Column(JSON, index=True, nullable=True)


# This works:
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
print("SQLite works")
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)

# One way to get a postgres database to test against:
# docker run --name test-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -d docker.io/postgres

# This fails:
engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:secret@localhost:5432")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
print("PostgreSQL works")
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

A solution was provided to me in the [a SQLAlchemy discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9530#discussioncomment-5414322). The feature @Erotemic and I were missing was `TypeEngine.with_variant`. Below, I apply it to my simple example to demonstrate the fix:

```py
from sqlalchemy import JSON, Column, Integer, Unicode, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
# Use JSON with SQLite and JSONB with PostgreSQL.
JSONVariant = JSON().with_variant(JSONB(), "postgresql")


class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = "nodes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    key = Column(Unicode(1023), index=True, nullable=False)
    ancestors = Column(JSONVariant, index=True, nullable=True)


# Both of these now work:
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
print("SQLite works")
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:secret@localhost:5432")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
print("PostgreSQL works")
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

Thanks to @CaselIT on GitHub for the quick help!